# Trazer apenas dados específicos do firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, ionic2, ionic3, firebase-database

Bem, estou tentando desenvolver um app com o ionic 3 e o Firebase. Mas estou tendo problemas. Está trazendo todos os pedidos, para todos os usuários(getAll). Queria saber qual a maneira correta pra eu trazer apenas os pedidos de usuário em si;

```
  getAll() {
return this.db.list('pedidos', ref => ref.orderByChild('name'))
  .snapshotChanges()
  .map(changes => {
    return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }));

  })
```

}

Comment: Informe qual produto do Firebase você está usando (exemplo: Realtime Database) e um exemplo de como seus dados estão organizados.

Comment: Realtime Database

Comment: {
  
  "pedidos" : {

    "-LMmARYYMaRcdeMmDpJm" : {
 
         "name" : "Produto1",
      
          "tel" : "1234"
    },
    
     "-LMmAwNOtNQ8Gnk9UWW5" : {

         "name" : "Produto2",
     
         "tel" : "321"
    }
  
 }

}

Answer (score 0):

Tente incluir o id do usuário na função dessa forma:

```
getListaUsuario() {
    var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    return firebase.database().ref('/pedidos/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
       return snapshot.val();
    });
}
```

Comment: Ele dá erro pois espera 2 argumentos apenas

Comment: Editei a resposta. Verifique se dessa forma você consegue o resultado de cada usuário.

Comment: Tenho uma var assim:  pedidos: Observable<any>; que recebe essa função que vc me passou. Ela é chamada no construtor da classe menu. Ele não esta aceitando, e está dando esse erro :
 Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null
    at PedidoProvider.webpackJsonp.252.PedidoProvider.getListaUsuario

Comment: No início da função, verifique se há usuário autenticado. Altere o início para if(firebase.auth().currentUser != null){ var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid; return ... }

Comment: Property 'snapshotChanges' does not exist on type '(snapshot: any) => any'.

Comment: Você pode substituir o conteúdo da sua função por `return snapshot.val();`. Editei a resposta novamente.

Comment: Ele não traz nada pra tela